# Contemporary Frequentists?

Tags: frequentist

My background is Bayesian. I know who to turn to for foundational discussion on this school of thought. To writers like MacKay, Gelman and Jaynes.

Who do I turn to for a recent exposition of frequentist thought? I want a (fairly) thorough account of what the underlying *philosophy* is. That is, what is the connection between probabilities and the real world, where does the usefulness of the system begin and end, arguments for the systematic superiority of the system.

I am aware there are different testing procedures within frequentism. But I'm craving someone willing to draw a line in the sand and say: 'This is what I think and here's why.' Even if it is a polemic in favour of eclecticism.

I'm also not asking for the math, for an explanation of the Kolmogorov system.

Stephen Senn might be a contender? But I'm not sure how committed he is to staking out a position. He seems more of a critic.

I'm asking for someone recent because I suspect many arguments based on pragmatic considerations will have found the facts moving underfoot.

Comment: Have a look here:  https://errorstatistics.com/

Comment: Cheers, I note Senn blogs there but I should check out more of the other authors too. Have you come across any individual articles there that might (partially) fit the bill?

Comment: DAS Fraser comes to mind. See his paper `Is Bayes Posterior just Quick and Dirty Confidence?`